# How to edit text filed behind on screen keyboard in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, keyboard, touch

We have developed a desktop application in C#, WPF. But new requirements come and now It has to run on touch screen devices. The problem occurs when editing an input filed that happens to be behind the onscreen keyboard. One solution is to use keyboard in docked mode - but that is a bad solutuion.

My solution should be something like shown on the image - keyboard would have additional filed. Which would correspond with the actual selected filed. I'm not sure how to (smart) implement this solution.
[image: Idea of solving the problem]

Has anybody had similar problem, and how did you solve it ?

Comment: I think [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/99652e87-113c-47fa-a8e7-60f11fc9f160/virtual-keyboard-covering-textbox?forum=winappswithcsharp) might help.

Comment: Thank you for the link but my application is not a **metro** application it's ordinary desktop app so it hasn't got access to Windows.UI.